# Slot machine program incorrect output

Tags: java

I've been working on a problem for my java class where we must create 3 slot machine objects and play them until we have run out of quarters. the first machine pay 30 quarters every 40th time it was play which has been played 30 times. The second machine pays out 60 quarters every 85th time it was played which was played 10 times and the third machine pays out 11 quarters every 10th time it was played which has been played 9 times. I've then counted the amount of times the machines have been played until they have run out of money. After i run the program, it says it played the machines 18770 times, however, i compared it to my other classmates and their output are different at a value of 33569 for each of them. Here's my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Slots {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Slotmachines game1 = new Slotmachines(30, 40);
    Slotmachines game2 = new Slotmachines(60, 85);
    Slotmachines game3 = new Slotmachines(11, 10);
    int quarters;
    int plays = 0;
    int play1, play2, play3;
    System.out.println("How many quarters are in the jar: \n");
    quarters = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many times has the first machine been played: \n");
    play1 = input.nextInt();
    play1 = game1.setCounter(play1);
    System.out.println("How many times has the second machine been played: \n");
    play2 = input.nextInt();
    play2 = game2.setCounter(play2);
    System.out.println("How many times has the third machine been played: \n");
    play3 = input.nextInt();
    play3 = game3.setCounter(play3);
    while(quarters != 0){
        plays++;
        quarters--;
        game1.game();
        quarters += game1.game();
        if(quarters != 0){
            plays++;
            quarters--;
            game2.game();
            quarters += game2.game();
        }
        if(quarters != 0){
            plays++;
            quarters--;
            game3.game();
            quarters += game3.game();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Marge played a total of " + plays + " times");



}
```

}

and here's the second class:

```
 public class Slotmachines {
    int payOut;
   int playLimit;
   int counter;



   public Slotmachines(int payOut, int playLimit) {
       this.payOut = payOut;
       this.playLimit = playLimit;
   }


   public void setPayOut(int payOut) {
       this.payOut = payOut;
   }

   public int getPayOut() {
       return payOut;
   }

   public void setPlayLimit(int playLimit) {
       this.playLimit = playLimit;
   }

   public int getPlayLimit() {
       return playLimit;
   }

   public int setCounter(int counter){
       this.counter = counter;
       return this.counter;
   }

   public int getSlotCounter() {
       return counter;
   }


   public int game() {
       int result = 0;
       counter++;
       if (counter >= playLimit) {
           counter = 0;
           result = payOut;
       }
       return result;
}
}
```

Here's my output:

How many quarters are in the jar:

5000

How many times has the first machine been played:

30

How many times has the second machine been played:

10

How many times has the third machine been played:

9

Marge played a total of 18770 times

Since the amount of times played is 18770, I would like to know why it's coming like this and why/how i could make the output equal to 33569.

Answer (score 1):

You are playing each machine twice in each iteration of the loop

```
game2.game();
quarters += game2.game();
```

While you are adjusting quarters and incrementing play for only one of them.